# I'm concerned about memory leak from RecordRTC url object

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

Using RecordRTC library, I'm hooking my React web application with webcam video recording, replaying and saving functionalities. Coming from native application development, I'm always concerned about potential memory leak which often can be easily diagnosed by checking system memory or lagging UI experience. In web applications, what diagnoses can you perform to see if a JS object is being created and deleted properly without leaks.

My concern appeared when I began integrating replay functionality as shown below. The **requestusermedia** method instantiates the webcam stream when React component mounts. In fact, the src state gets assigned with the url to the video stream. Afterwards, anytime a stop button is clicked, a new url, representing a webm file of recorded video, is created and assigned to the same src state. The functionality of streaming and replaying works as planned. But, I'm concerned that continuation of creating and replaying video, essentially creating a new url wrapping webm file would only result in memory leak unless the browser is refreshed.

Are there any checks in the browser level I could conduct to diagnose this? Or is this something I shouldn't be concerned of at all in the web application world?

```
requestUserMedia() {
    captureUserMedia((stream) => {
        this.setState({ src: window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)}); 
    });
}

handleRecord(){

    if (!this.state.record) {
        captureUserMedia((stream) => {
            var recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
                type: 'video'
            });
            recorder.startRecording();
            this.state.recordVideo = recorder;
        });
    } else {
        var recorder = this.state.recordVideo
        recorder.stopRecording(() => {
            var blob = recorder.getBlob();
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            this.setState({ src: url })
        });
    }
    let newRecordState = !this.state.record
    this.setState({
        record: newRecordState
    })
}
```

Comment: Javascript has garbage collection. An object that is not referenced anymore will be garbage collected if this was your concern. If you keep unnecessary references to objects you don't need thats of course an implementation problem. Chrome has a performance tab in the inspection toolbar that can record memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the videos src to a string created with URL.createObjectURL has been deprecated for that reason. Set video.srcObject = stream instead.

For the second createObjectURL use URL.revokeObjectURL to revoke the previous one.